# Difference between hooks Plugin_loaded and admin_int?

Tags: hooks, actions, admin-init

As per my understanding, functions attached to plugin_loaded and admin_init hooks are called whenever any admin page is loaded. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/) fires once activated plugins have loaded. This fires on both admin and public screens.

[`admin_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) fires as an admin screen or script is being initialized. This fires only on admin screens.

---

The typical order for firing of hooks on the admin screen is:

1. muplugins_loaded - *this is the first hook available to must-use plugins*
2. registered_taxonomy
3. registered_post_type
4. plugins_loaded - *this is the first hook available to regular plugins*
5. auth_cookie_valid
6. set_current_user
7. load_textdomain
8. sanitize_comment_cookies
9. setup_theme
10. unload_textdomain
11. after_setup_theme - *this is the first hook available to themes*
12. init
13. widgets_init
14. register_sidebar
15. wp_register_sidebar_widget
16. wp_default_styles
17. wp_default_scripts
18. debug_bar_enqueue_scripts
19. wp_loaded - *This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.*
20. auth_redirect
21. admin_menu
22. pre_get_users
23. pre_user_query
24. admin_init
25. ... lots of other stuff

---

As you can see, a lot happens between `plugins_loaded` and `admin_init`.

Hooks on the public side are similar to those above, with the notable absence of `admin_init`.